# React socket io client emitting twice to node server

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, sockets, socket.io

I am making a react app with node as backend. They communicate using socket-io. The problem I am having an issue where react does and `emit` to send data to node, but does it twice, thereby making a double submission. For example, with the login form the terminal output looks like this:

```
[nodemon] starting `node --trace-warnings central-server.js`
web server running on port 5000
client GuRD1JAb_J1xn4O4AAAB successfully connected
{ CompanyID: 'BigCompany', Password: 'SecretPassword' }
{ CompanyID: 'BigCompany', Password: 'SecretPassword' }
```

Here is the front end app:

```js
import { useState } from "react";
import Form from "./components/Signup-Form.js";
import { io } from "socket.io-client";
const socket = io("http://192.168.43.118:5000", {
    withCredentials: true,
    extraHeaders: {
        "react-client": "react-client",
    },
});
function App() {
    const [userData, setUserData] = useState({});

    if (Object.entries(userData).length === 0) {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <div className="textContainer">
                    <h1>Welcome</h1>
                    <h3>You can Log in or Sign Up here</h3>
                </div>
                <Form setUserData={setUserData} />
            </div>
        );
    } else {
        socket.emit("signup", userData);
        return <p>Data sent successfully</p>;
    }
}

export default App;
```

The server:

```js
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var server = require("http").Server(app);

const dotenv = require("dotenv");
dotenv.config();
const WS_PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const io = require("socket.io")(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: ["http://localhost:3000", "http://192.168.43.118:3000"],
        methods: ["GET", "POST"],
        transports: ["websocket", "polling", "flashsocket"],
        allowedHeaders: ["react-client"],
        credentials: true,
    },
});
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    console.log(`client ${socket.id} successfully connected`);
    socket.on("signup", (data) => {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
server.listen(WS_PORT, () => console.log("web server running on port", WS_PORT));
```

The `App.js` file is the only one using the socket at the moment. Also, when I save the file and the server auto reloads, I get the client creates a connection 3 times instead of just one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't be performing asynchronous or event-driven operations inside the render code. Every time your `App` component gets rendered (e.g. when state changes), it'll also perform your `socket.emit` again if `userData` is still empty.

*As what's causing `App` to render twice, I can't tell from your code. But you should assume that React can re-render your components at any time anyway, so try to prevent issues like this.*

You can use [`React.useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) with a dependency array of `[]` to perform an operation only once when the component gets mounted. In your case, it's even better to just have a regular callback though:

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";


function App() {
    const [dataSent, setDataSent] = useState(false);

    const sendData = (data) => {
        if (dataSent) return; // Just to make sure
        socket.emit('signup', data);
        setDataSent(true);
    };

    // If you want to actuall wait for a response to display:
    const [response, setResponse] = useState(undefined);
    useEffect(() => {
        socket.on('signup-response', setResponse);
        return () => {
            // This function gets called when the effect gets retriggered
            // (which never happens because of the [] dependency array)
            // or if the component gets unmouted.
            // We remove the event listener here:
            socket.off('signup-response', setResponse);
        };
    }, []);
    if (response) return <p>Got response: {response}</p>;


    if (dataSent) {
        return <p>Data sent successfully</p>;
    } else {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <div className="textContainer">
                    <h1>Welcome</h1>
                    <h3>You can Log in or Sign Up here</h3>
                </div>
                <Form setUserData={sendData} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I've added in a way for you to listen to a response from your server. You can use this for any data/event though, which the server can also send several times.